# How do I center the current line in the screen?

Tags: cursor-movement, scrolling

Is there a way to center the line I'm editing in the screen? This is sometimes needed to see a bit more context above and below the current line.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The `z.` and `zz` commands will recenter the line the cursor is on.  `z.` also moves the cursor to the first non-whitespace character in the line, while `zz` keeps the cursor where it is.

There are similar commands for the top (`z<CR>`/`zt`) and bottom (`z-`/`zb`) of the window.

The versions of these commands that end in a letter keep the cursor column, while the ones ending in punctuation move the cursor.

Answer (score 14):

Type `zz` to center the current line in the screen:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! I added this to my BufReadPost autocmd so I resume editing with the cursor line restored and centered on screen: `au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | "normal! g'\"zz"`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in normal mode you can use `zz` to do so. But as the [docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#zz) forewarn, be careful with capslock as `ZZ` will write the buffer to file and quit.

Comment: For whatever reason this became a huge point of contention on another SO/SE thread... the consensus seemed to be that you should hold shift down indefinitely as needed and remap the caps lock key at the system level to remove the temptation, et voilà, no more caps lock whoopsies. Otherwise it's your own fault. I'm guessing they've never had to deal with preprocessor macros...

Answer (score 4):

In normal mode, `zz` will move the line currently under the cursor to the center of the screen.

Comment: I managed to forget that this just moves the SCREEN, not the cursor line. So if you've just opened a file and are wondering why it does nothing, it's because the current line is the top line and thus can't be moved.