# Customizing the functionality of Ctrl-D is it possible - so=50 only with ctrl+d and ctrl+u

Tags: key-bindings, scrolling

I have to navigate through a large code base and it seems the thing that best suits me is the setting for scroll offset

```
:set scrolloff=50
```

However if I have to click on the random spot on the screen or move to a random spot on the screen using `/` `scrolloff=50` doesn't help.

Is there a way for me to tell vim that set `scrolloff=50` only when I press `<C-d>` or `<C-u>`? After every `<C-d>` or `<C-u>` return scroll offset to 0 so it will be `scrolloff=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by simple making a mapping:

```
nnoremap <C-d> :set scrolloff=50<CR><C-d>:set scrolloff=0<CR>
```

If I understand your intention correct, then centring the screen with `zz` may actually be more appropriate though:

```
nnoremap <C-d> <C-d>zz
```

Also see: [How do I center the current line in the screen?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/40/51).

I recommend you read [`:help key-mapping`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#key%2dmapping) and/or [the appropriate chapters of Learn Vimscript the hard way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/03.html), by the way.